# regex from txt file python

Tags: python, regex, if-statement, txt

I'm building a task manager and I need to find tasks in a txt file assigned to a user who is logged in. I added the output from my txt file to a variable counts and then I use regex to find the needed txt .My problem comes in when I try and match the output with re.findall().

this is the text file I read from

```
admin, Register Users with taskManager.py, Use taskManager.py to add the usernames and passwords for all team members that will be using this program., 10 Oct 2019, 20 Oct 2019, No
admin, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to assign each team member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No
chris, build task manager, finish manager, 29 June 2022, 22 May 2025, No
tony, build new suit, builing a new iron man suit, 5 July 2022, 25 October 2023, no
```

this is my code

```
elif menu == "vm":
                #find_tasks = input("Please enter your username: ")
                with open(r"C:\Users\27711\Desktop\PROGRAMMING\Bootcamp lvl 1\task 20 Capstone\tasks.txt", 'r') as file3:
                    for line in file3:
                        iteration = line.split(", ")

                        counts = f'''\nAssigned to:\t {iteration[0]}
                        \nTask:\t {iteration[1]}
                        \nDate assigned:\t {iteration[3]}
                        \nDue Date:\t {iteration[4]}
                        \nTask Complete:\t {iteration[5]}
                        \nTask Description: \n{iteration[2]}\n'''

                        found = re.findall('Task:\s*(.*)\s*Assigned to:.\s*(admin)\s*Date assigned:\s*(.*)\s*Due Date:\s*(.*)\s*Task Complete:\s*(.*)\s*Task Description:\s*(.*)', counts)

                        for item in found:
                            print(f'''\nTask:\t {item[1]}
                            \nAssigned to:\t {item[0]}
                            \nDate assigned:\t {item[2]}
                            \nDue Date:\t {item[0]}
                            \nTask Complete:\t {item[0]}
                            \nTask Description: \n{item[0]}\n''')
```

So my code made the txt file contents into this

```
Task:    Register Users with taskManager.py

Assigned to:     admin

Date assigned:   10 Oct 2019

Due Date:        20 Oct 2019

Task Complete:   No


Task Description:
Use taskManager.py to add the usernames and passwords for all team members that will be using this program.
```

Why wont my regex work on this I need to print only the tasks that is assigned to the user thats logged in

Comment: Newlines. Use https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.S .

Comment: @9769953 i swapped \s for \n still  wont return anything

Comment: You have \s after various ":", so expecting a newline there doesn't make sense.